# Can I use "this" with delegating constructors?

Tags: c++11, delegating-constructor

C++11 introduced the possibility of delegating construction from one constructor to another - ["delegating constructors"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26199431/1593077).

But - when doing that, can we use the this pointer? e.g. as an argument to one of the constructors we're delegating to? It's not trivial to assume that we can while the "real constructor" has not actually been invoked yet.

Answer (score -1):

For a definitive answer one would need to read the standard (and even there it might not be entirely clear, see @BenjaminBanner's comment). But in practice - yes, apparently we can use `this` in constructor delegation.

The following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int x_, void* p_) : x(x_), p(p_) { }
    A(void* p_) : A(0, p_) { }
    A() : A(this) { }
    int x;
    void* p;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << "&a == "  << &a  << "\n";
    std::cout << "a.p == " << a.p << "\n";
}
```

[compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/yUDp1E) (GodBolt) with all of GCC, clang and MSVC. They do not warn about doing this, even with `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra` or `/W4` for MSVC.

It also [runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a809df7a6cf9a3ee) (coliru.com) and produces the expected output (at the link you have the g++-compiled version, clang++ can be checked there as well).

Comment: To me this seems to boil down to whether `this` is valid before any constructor is invoked which would seem reasonable but hard to find in the standard. http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#6 seems to suggest that no constructor was invoked when delegating to that "copy constructor". With a ref to the validity range of `this` and `class.base.init` we might have an answer (`class.this` doesn't even seem to cover use outside of function bodies, even though it can e.g., appear in default arguments, http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#8).

Comment: This seems to be a poor answer given the point @Deduplicator raised and given that is is a self-answered question.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What are you quoting? I didn't use the word "works" anywhere. I said it compiles, meaning that these major 3 compilers accept it as valid. Anyway, see edit.

Comment: @einpoklum: _I said it compiles, meaning that these major 3 compilers accept it as valid_. I would argue that in the context of C++ this approach is not sound. Nothing in this answer shows that this is _valid_ for e.g., arbitrary class sizes, inheritance hierarchies, or optimization or LTO flags.

Comment: I guess the real question is why would you? The delegated constructor has a pointer to this already... it is called this!

Comment: @GemTaylor: The `p` pointer is not always used to store `this`; that's just a special case expressed by the delegating constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: It is not rejected as invalid syntax; I've also enabled a bunch of warnings and made sure the compiler don't warn about it. So, either it's valid, or the compilers are all missing it

Comment: @einpoklum, _So, either it's valid, or the compilers are all missing it_, that is dangerously off, see `[defns.undefined]` (_Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message). Many erroneous program constructs do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed._)

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: Compilers generally warn about undefined behavior; not warning about this would be 'missing it'.

Comment: @einpoklum, _Compilers generally warn about undefined behavior_, that is incorrect and like I wrote an unsound and dangerous approach to C++. Anybody with more than a passing knowledge of C++ should be aware of this.